# In NestJs DatadogTraceModule causes another Injectable with REQUEST scope to become DEFAULT scope

Tags: nestjs

I have a class annotated like:

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class SomeRequestScopedClass {
```

This worked as expected until I introduced `DatadogTraceModule` in its dependency chain. See https://github.com/codebrick-corp/nestjs-ddtrace/blob/main/src/datadog-trace.module.ts Now it's behaving as `DEFAULT` scoped.

I can add:

```
scope: Scope.REQUEST,
```

to the provider of `SomeRequestScopedClass`, but I'm curious what might cause the `Injectable` annotation to not be working anymore.